# I want to know what Maven is

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I am building system using gwt and we are using Maven.
Anyone who can explain what is maven simply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google "what is maven" and click on the top link.

Comment: *I want to know what maven is // I want you to show me* (Foreigner)

Answer (score 3):

Maven is a managment and building tool helping you to resolve dependencies (libraries/jars) and manage it automaticly for you. Try it yourself and give it a chance, you wont regret it ;)

-> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Concepts

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a project management tool with build capabilities :) It is meant to standarize the structure of projects and to solve other common problems in java projects :)

You could look into the wikipedia (or better, the maven project site) to get a better explanation!

Comment: 1337 reputation :D ... Hope u don't get a vote ^^

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: just kidding about leet -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet , dont take it too serious ;)